# Can you please help on the mixed tensor definition in my textbook?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, tensors

In my textbook it says:

A mixed tensor $r$ times covariant and $s$ times contravariant is a multilinear functional $W$

$$W(\alpha_1 , ... \alpha_r , \vec v_1 , ... , \vec v_s)=(\alpha_1)_{i_1} ...(\alpha_s)_{i_s}{W_{j_1 ... j_r}^{i_1 ... i_s}} \vec v_1^{j_1}...\vec v_r^{j_r}$$

I was hoping someone can make this equation clear to me, at first I'm not even sure why the inputs are what they are I thought it would have been

$W(\vec v_1,...,\vec v_r, \alpha_1,...,\alpha_s)$

And I have no clue what the right hand side is, I have tried digesting it but I just don't have a clue.

Would appreciate the help, thanks.

[image]

Comment: You're completely wrong that the book messed up. There should be $r$ vectors and $s$ covectors. (They have the domain of the function correct, but then wrote down the wrong formula.)

Comment: Oops. Typo. You are completely RIGHT, not wrong. Sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your text book, a mixed tensor $r$-$s$ takes $r$ 1-forms and $s$-vectors and gives you a scalar, a real number for example.

The right-hand-side is the expression of $W$ acting over $\alpha$'s and $\vec{v}$'s in coordinates (there are several sums ommited). Each $(\alpha_a)_i$ is the $i$-th component of the 1-form $\alpha_a$. Similarly, $\vec{v}_b^j$ is the $j$-th of the vector $\vec{v}_b$. $W_{j_1\dots j_r}^{i_1\dots i_s}$ are the components of $W$.

You can thought $W$ as a generalization of a matrix. A matrix $A$ takes a 1-form $\alpha = (\alpha_1\ldots \alpha_n)$ and a vector $\vec{v}=(v_1\dots v_n)^T$ and gives you a scalar

$$A(\alpha,v) = \alpha A \vec{v} = \sum_{i,j} A_i^j \alpha_j v^i. $$

Or using Einstein's convention

$$A(\alpha,v) = A_i^j \alpha_j v^i $$

(repited indices up and down sum). In this case $A_i^j$ are the components of the matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1^1 & \dots & a_1^n \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_n^1 & \dots & a_n^n 
\end{pmatrix} $$

and $A(\alpha,v)$ is just the matrix multiplication

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
\alpha_1 & \cdots &\alpha_n
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1^1 & \dots & a_1^n \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_n^1 & \dots & a_n^n 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
v^1 & \dots & v^n
\end{pmatrix} .
$$

For higher dimensions is the same, but you can' write $W$ as a matrix because it is $r\cdot s$-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for this, My last confusion is that why are the one-forms elements of $V$ instead of $V^*$? Or is this a mistake in the book

Comment: No no. $\alpha\in V^*$ actually. One forms are linear functions over $V$, and they have a vector space structure $V^*$. If your book says $\alpha\in V$ it is a mistake for sure. Note that $\alpha$ is also a tensor $\alpha:V\rightarrow \mathbb R$, $\alpha(v)=\sum_i\alpha_i v^i$.

Comment: This isn't right. The book switched covariant and contravariant when they wrote their formula. A covariant tensor eats a vector, and a contravariant tensor eats a covector.